# Prove that one of the roots of a poly lies outside the unit circle in the complex plane

Tags: complex-numbers

please could you help me with the following problem. I need to show that a particular multistep method in numerical analysis satisfies the root condition. I have reduced the problem to showing that $p(\omega)=a-9\omega + (8-a)\omega^2+\omega^3$ has a root outside the unit circle in the complex plane ($a\in\mathbb{R})$. Please could you help me proceed.

Comment: Have you learned Rouche's theorem?

Comment: No I haven't. I need to solve this to show a result in numerical analysis about multistep methods satisfying the root condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

Let $\omega_1,\omega_2,\omega_3$ be the three roots. Then, 
$$\omega_1+\omega_2+\omega_3=a-8$$
$$\omega_1\omega_2\omega_3=a$$
Can $|\omega_i|<1$ for all $i$?

Comment: Thank you, it seems obvious when you put it like this!